# override / customise jbehave date converter

Tags: type-conversion, jbehave

My story steps are something like this:

```
When the user selects '<past>' date in field start date
When the user selects '<future>' date in field start date
```

Corresponding method in the steps java file is

```
@When("the user selects '$datevalue' date in field $field")
public void selectDate(Date dateValue, String fieldName) {
...
}
```

Customised date converter

```
parameterConverters.addConverters(new ParameterConverters.DateConverter() {

    @Override
    public Object convertValue(String value, Type type) {
        if (value.equals("<future>")){
            Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            return cal.getTime();
        } else if (value.equals("<past>")){
            Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
            return cal.getTime();
        }
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new ParameterConvertionFailed("Failed to convert value "
                    + value + " with date format yyyy-MM-dd", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Type type) {
        if (type instanceof Class<?>) {
            return String.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) type);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

But the customised date converter has no effect, it seems to me that the default implementation is always executed as I get the error 
org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters$ParameterConvertionFailed: Failed to convert value  with date format dd/MM/yyyy

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If I run your example, I get the same error as you. It occurs because of the accept-method, more precisely because of the following line:

```
return String.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) type);
```

I do not know exactly how the method is supposed to work (Javadoc of JBehave does not help here). To solve the issue, there are two possibilities:

One is not to override the accept-method, the other is to change the accept-method as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean accept(Type type)
{
    if (type instanceof Class<?>)
    {
        return Date.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) type);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what point you are trying to make here. Could you please elaborate?